# Can't work with server after modifying /lib/libc.so.6

Tags: linux, centos, libc6

I have a CentOS server, VPS. After running this command I can't work with server and get the same error in all actions (SSH, Login, ls and ...)

The command:

```
ln -s /lib/libc.so.1  /lib/libc.so.6 -f
```

And the error is:

```
/sbin/shutdown: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have VNC to server but because I can't login to server, that's unusable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you overwrote one of the links for your C library. Why did you do this? There's no reason you should be modifying links or library files.

Where did `/lib/libc.so.1` come from? Cecking my CentOS 4, 5 and 6 systems, that file is not included in the distribution.

What version of CentOS is this?
On CentOS 5, libc.so.6 should link to libc-2.5.so.

```
[root@xt ~]# ls -l /lib/libc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1689728 Apr 20 07:32 /lib/libc-2.5.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 Apr 29 22:27 /lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.5.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You *may* be able to recover from your error by running `ldconfig`.